# Error assigning Synapse role using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-synapse

i am trying to assign an in-bulit role in Synapse through Terraform but i get an Error.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "example" {
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.syn_ws.id
  role_name            = "Synapse Administrator"
  principal_id         = "<user_objectid>"       # alternatively data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  depends_on = [azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule.example]
}
```

Below is the error generated, it seems like there is authorization missing, but all other steps to create the resource group, storage, workspace etc. work.

```
Error: listing synapse role definitions accesscontrol.RoleDefinitionsClient#ListRoleDefinitions: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://synapse-da-dev.dev.azuresynapse.net/roleDefinitions?api-version=2020-08-01-preview&scope=workspaces%2Fsynapse-da-dev": authenticationrequired        
│
│   with module.rg-synapse.azurerm_synapse_role_assignment.example,
│   on ..\modules\rg-synapse\main.tf line 113, in resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "example":
│  113: resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "example" {
```

Any input is greatly appreciated thank you so much!

Comment: How did you end up resolving this @Robert? I have a similar issue where access to my Synapse workspace is restricted, thus I have a FW rule that needs to be applied before attempting the role assignment. Currently, I'm encountering various timeout related issues.

Comment: @MattStannett It ended up being my companies network setup. Probably not very helpful to you, but one other thing to try is to run powershell directly outside of vs code and or use a current terraform version. I vaguely remember, that TF also writes more verbose errors somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your terraform agent have access to synapse, if you are blocking all public access to synapse , then add the IP of terraform agent to allowed sources.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It looks like my companies network setup did end up blocking the request. Weirdly enough only this one.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I appreciate the response.